# How to select rows where the value appears in any one of several columns in another table?

Tags: sql

Suppose I have two tables in SQL, one containing some data about a group of people, while another table containing a list of alternative names of those people:

```
Table A:
Name         SomeData
Bob          12345
Robert       23456
Alice        34567
Chris        45678
...
```

```
Table B:
TrueName    AltName1    AltName2    OtherCols
Robert      Rob         Bob         0000
Alice       null        null        0000
```

I would like to select all rows in Table A where the Name matches any one of the alternative names in Table B, and additionally change "Name" to be the value for "TrueName". In the example given, I would like to obtain the following:

```
Name       SomeData
Robert     12345
Robert     23456
Alice      34567
```

(note that any data concerning Chris is left out since he is not in Table B)

I can assume that no two person share a name or alternative name. Can this be done with a SELECT command?

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far because "I would like to select all rows..." is not showing us your effort. Also, what database do you use ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is `exists` to answer your question about matching names:

```
select a.*
from a
where exists (select 1
              from b
              where a.name in (b.TrueName, b.AltName1, b.AltName2)
             );
```

However, you need a `join` if you want data from the second table:

```
select b.TrueName, a.*
from a join
     b
     on a.name in (b.TrueName, b.AltName1, b.AltName2);
```